# MUI - Copying text inside ListItemText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am not able to copy text inside  component from material UI. What I can change in order to do that?

```
<ListItem key={staff._id}
            className={background_colour}
            onClick={par(set_viewing, component, staff)}>
            {checkboxes}
            {avatar}
            **<ListItemText primary={text} />**
            <Button  onClick={() => {navigator.clipboard.writeText(email)}} size='small' variant="string">{email}</Button>
            {renderActionButtons}
        </ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add custom `className` for `ListItemText`

```
<ListItemText className="select_text" primary={text} />
```

so you can override MUI style

**style.css**

```
.select_text {
    user-select: text !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, eventually i was not supposed to change default styles so I ended up adding a Button with onClick copy function.